# Of what fell beast did this olive drab carcass come?

Tags: set-identification

I think I have assembled the remains of *some* dread creature:

[image: some dread creature]

I'm pretty sure that I wouldn't have enough elements to reassemble this, but I would at least like to know what it looked like in it's prime.

Comment: The snake from Harry Potter had *some* of those pieces, too.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I actually did come across some Harry Potter tail pieces in my own(largely unsuccessful) searching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you have [SandGreen parts](http://www.peeron.com/cgi-bin/invcgis/psearch?query=SandGreen&limit=color2part) from probably two different sets...

The dinosaur head ([x158](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/x158)), 2 tail sections ([40396](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/40396) and [40379](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/40379)), 2 sloped pieces ([3039](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/3039)), and black Technic brick ([3700](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/3700)) are likely the remains of a [Baby Ankylosaurus](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/5950-1)/[Young Ankylosaurus](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7000-1):

[image]

The wedge plate ([2419](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/2419)) and curved brick ([6091](http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/6091)) are likely parts from a [Red Planet Cruiser](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7311-1) (also in the [Alien Discovery](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/78777-1) set):

[image]

Comment: The actual theme was called Life on Mars. I have both sets.

Comment: Yes these should be the sets. I'm very surprised to find that I do in, in fact have most of the pieces of the Ankylosaurus. I shall bring it back to life!

Comment: @RedriderX: Just be sure not to fill in any missing pieces with [frog](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?S=LLCA31-1) [pieces](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/7606-1) when you revive it. [Jurassic Park](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0107290/) shows us it could have unintended consequences. ;)